# Target an elements pseudo attribute to initiate Rellax.js parallax effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax, pseudo-element

I have a div element with an inline style that sets the background. What I wanted to do was add another background image that overlays the background image set by the inline css via the `::before` pseudo class and have that be the class that Rellax.js initiates for a parallax effect.

**Results so far:** `rellax.min.js:14 Rellax: The elements you're trying to select don't exist.` which makes sense because I don't think the pseudo element is in the DOM. The backgrounds do render like I planned overlaying each other.

**Question:** Is it possible to reference the pseudo attribute of an element?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="right bttk-cta-bg" style="background:url(/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Arrow-Down-BG.png) repeat; background-position: top left"> 
    ::Before
```

**Rellex.js**

```
    <script>
  // Also can pass in optional settings block
  var rellax = new Rellax('.bttk-cta-bg::before', {
    speed: -2,
    center: false,
    wrapper: null,
    round: true,
    vertical: true,
    horizontal: false
  });
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
  .bttk-cta-bg::before {
    content: '';
    background: url(/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/up-arrows.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
   }
```

Comment: Are you dead set on using the `::before` pseudo class to achieve this? Might be easier to simply wrap this div along with another div in a container div, and giving the new child div the 2nd image. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: This html is part of a widget that is dynamically created. Or your recommendation would  have been my first choice. I just saw the ::Before in there and figured I would hook into that.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe its possible to target the `::Before` class with js.

Comment: Hey so I was answering some questions today and there was a question I answered that reminded me of this question where I was able to change things with js that affected the psuedo elements in CSS.  You might be able to backdoor some info to your `::before` using the `attr()` command in CSS. Check my answer on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74452548/how-can-i-show-the-number-of-items-in-an-shopping-card-icon-from-javascript/74452913#74452913